# Print the digits of the integer n from left to right

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    while (n != 0)
    {
        digit = n / 10;
        n = n / 10;
        printf("%d ", digit);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

## Heading

////////////////////////////////////
input 1234, output 1 2 3 4. But I have a problem with zero, if I enter 0123, output just only 1 2 3

Comment: How is that incorrect? (Also, your algorithm cannot work the way you describe it.)

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense.  Numbers do not have any kind of sense of how they were created, or whether one or more leading zeros were present in their textual representation.  How many different flavors of 123 do you think there are?  Hint:  Only one.

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/6n4yNO)

Comment: digit = `n % 10`?!

Comment: Do you want the answer in base 2 or base 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a homework assignment, so I won't write the code for you, but I can tell you the algorithm.  Convert n to a string (see [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/?kw=itoa)), then iterate over that string, printing each character one at a time.

Comment: Thanks you very much, which I really need is the algoritm,

Comment: If you find a response useful, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print leading zeros, you can't convert the input to a number because that will "remove" leading zeros. You need to keep the input as text.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char in[100];
    int i = 0;
    if (fgets(in, 100, stdin))
    {
        for (i=0; in[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        {
            if (isdigit(in[i]))
            {
                printf("%d ", in[i]-'0');
            }
            else
            {
                 // Not a digit - add error handling here
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not wrong, just not necessary `i < 100`. `fgets` insures a *nul-terminated* string, checking `in[i]` is sufficient. Also, reading and printing a string of digits one character as a time converted to a decimal and format as an `int` is slightly different than printing the digits of an integer in order one at a time.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - ...add yes, this is different from printing digits of an integer - that's the point of my answer. If OP wants to print leading zeros of the given input, the input **can't** be converted to an integer before printing.